# Search Yahoo Answers using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to crawl yahoo and get the top 10 results matching a keyword.

I am using [this](https://in.search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=AibrWnqoneznrEAiS9bG0aOuitIF?p=solar+systems&toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8&fr=yfp-t-405) link to crawl the results

Code I am using for this is:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://in.search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=AibrWnqoneznrEAiS9bG0aOuitIF?p=solar+systems&toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8&fr=yfp-t-405").get();
            for(Element dc : doc.select("div#doc.uh3-p uh3lite"))
        {
            System.out.println("data");
                    for(Element dd : doc.select("div#bd"))
            {
                for(Element results : doc.select("div#results"))
                {
                    for(Element wb : doc.select("div#web"))
                    {
                        Elements data=wb.select("span");
                        if(data.size()>0)
                        {
                               System.out.println(data.get(0).text());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex); 
    }
}
```

I am getting no results with it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you read the robots.txt file for the site? I am pretty sure it does not allow web crawling.

Comment: @JechtTyre Yahoo allows us to crawl its searched links..I was able to crawl the data..

Comment: just because you are able to doesn't mean it is allowed. Check this link: [http://search.yahoo.com/robots.txt](http://search.yahoo.com/robots.txt). You should be able to see the universal "disallow: /search"

Comment: @JechtTyre Okk I have seen robots.txt file in your link..but if yahoo does not allow to crawl its data, then how was I able to crawl it..infact i was also able to crawl data of google while its robots.txt file also has universal "disallow: /search" as you can see in the link : http://www.google.com/robots.txt

Comment: Look. Your a college student so you well know plagiarism. Can you do it? As easy as in any assignment you're given. Is it still allowed?You might get away with once or twice but once you're caught, you get the axe; dropped from college or get your IP address banned.

Comment: @JechtTyre I am not doing any kind of plagiarism..I am just using JSoup library to crawl google or yahoo like I am using it to crawl other sites which allow their data to be crawled..and as you can see my code(the code i have specified in my question above), it is a simple crawling code without any sign of plagiarism..also if yahoo would have not allowed me to crawl its data, then Jsoup parser could not have been able to connect to yahoo link at first step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selector is wrong.

```
doc.select("div#doc.uh3-p uh3lite")
```

If you want to select two classes, use the period `.` before each class name.

```
doc.select("div#doc.uh3-p.uh3lite")
```

A space in the selector means something entirely different.

EDIT: Also, you refer back to `doc` in each of your nested for loop selectors. I assume you mean to be referring to the selected element from the previous for loop.

i.e.

```java
    for(Element dc : doc.select("div#doc.uh3-p uh3lite"))
    {
        System.out.println("data");

        for(Element dd : dc.select("div#bd")) // note doc was changed to dc
        {
            for(Element results : dd.select("div#results")) // note doc was changed to dd
            {
                // etc...
```

And finally how will you know if you get any results since your print statements are commented out?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but still I am getting no result

Comment: I am able to use the rest of your selectors just fine. You should update your code in the original post. Please take into consideration the code formatting techniques I edited into your post and apply them to your original code.